# Is it more efficient to put the more common case first in an IF statement?

Tags: php

Here was my recent task

A particular variable will sometimes be empty (except for some white spaces which are concatenated into it), in which case I wanted to echo an "error" message

Here's my if statement:

```
if(preg_match("/^\s+$/",$var[$i])) {
  echo "Description not available";
} else {
  echo $var[$i];
}
```

My question is, since the error is the exception rather than the norm, is it more efficient to write the query anticipating the most common case first?

E.g.:

```
if(!preg_match("/^\s+$/",$var[$i])) {
  echo $var[$i];
} else {
  echo "Description not available";
}
```

Or perhaps there is a better way to write this that *would* be more efficient?

It's fair to say that the difference(s) is/are not appreciable, but there may be no difference at all! I don't know how the PHP engine works through these statements

Comment: The order of `if` vs `else` makes no difference, but `preg_match` is pretty heavy duty fo that check. `if ( ! empty( trim($var[$i]) ) )` would probably be faster, or just `if ( trim($var[$i]) )` which is shorthand fir the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some benchmarks a couple of years ago (on PHP 5.x) and I wasn't able to clearly say if there's time or space optimisation using or not the negative operator.

It all depends on your readability, and for this, my opinion is into functions/methods to start with the error cases first. The aim is to reduce the nested levels into my functions.

Example: instead of

```php
function foo() 
{
    if ($a === 1) {
        if ($b === 2) {
            if ($c === 3) {
                return doD();
            } else {
                return doC();
            }
        } else {
            return doB();
        }
    } else {
        return doA();
    }
}
```

You can do

```php
function foo() 
{
    if ($a !== 1) {
        return doA();
    }
    if ($b !== 2) {
        return doB();
    }
    if ($c !== 3) {
        return doC();
    }
    return doD();
}
```

See how nested level is reduced simply by switching the boolean condition.

But of course, this is only a personnal use and preference, there's no rule and no optimisation here.

Comment: Even better readability wise would be to use `elseif` - only one branch can be reached because of the `return`s, but that wouldn't be obvious at a glance with more complex code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah sure, stupid brain I have... I edit

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter. Thats user preference. But I think more people like to write the most common case in the beginning. Anyways, why are you using a preg_match for your example?

This would be the easiest way of writing that:

```
if(!empty($var[$i]) && !ctype_space($var[$i]) {       
    echo $var[$i];
} else {
    echo "Description not available!";
}
```

Like you see - I am using the most common case in the Beginning.

I have edited my answer to check for whitespaces. Anyways, with the whitespace-check the regex is probably the more-clean solution.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the empty function :) I'll give that a try too then

Comment: `empty()` won't return true for a string containing spaces, only one that is truly empty.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I have not read that part, I will edit my questions @IMSoP

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know there was a `ctype_space`! Not sure why you've added an extra `if` statement though.

Answer (score 1):

There is effectively no difference. In general aim for logic in the if() that is the easiest to understand (an extra ! increases the human parsing complexity). That said, if the body of the if ends up being relatively large with a short amount of code in the else, e.g. for an error, you may prefer to invert the logic and put the error first so that at first glance, both the error and most of the logic can be seen together.

Answer (score 1):

If you have nested `if` statements you can organize them to test the most common result first to speed things up.

If you have more complex statements containing `AND`s and/or `OR`s in them you can arrange the statements to "fail faster". F.e. using an `AND` and putting the most likely option to be false first would allow the program to skip the second test altogether more frequently.

Your given example doesn't do either of these though. So while it IS possible to speed things up by reordering `IF` statements, it is not possible in your specific example (unless you follow the idea given by @Xatenev).

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, lacking examples or references but it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

This is better and faster i guess

```
if ( ! empty( trim($var[$i]) ) ){
     echo "Description available!";
   }
else{
     echo "Description not available!";
   }
```